# How to add values of multiple table in one array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using opencart database to make a simple product app which shows product with it's category.

here i got the problem i already made an array by looping the values to an array now the database contains 3 or more tables which contains category_id in common 1 contains id with image link another contains name. these two are important to me. here is code to understand

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_category";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories[] =$row;
}
```

this code makes an array which contains category_id, category_image which i can further use by

```
foreach ( $categories as $category){
    echo "the category id is $category['category_id']";
}
```

now the another table is oc_category_description which contains name of category. 
how can i make it to be in one array so i can use $category['name']; to echo it.

i already tried many ways among which i queried 2 tables in one

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_category, oc_category_description";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $categories[] =$row;
}
```

this method worked but it slowed the app and shown one result for four times

here is what i think every table has category_id which is common in every table i would like to use it to add name and other description from oc_category_description.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` your `category_id` in your query like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_category, oc_category_description 
        GROUP BY oc_category.category_id";
```

Or even you can `JOIN` them like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_category
        LEFT JOIN oc_category_description 
        ON oc_category.category_id = oc_category_description.category_id 
        GROUP BY oc_category.category_id";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is saying "Column 'category_id' in group statement is ambiguous". why is it saying that ?

Comment: See my edit now...I thought it is in `oc_category` ONLY.

Comment: Still not working it's showing the same result in loop while i use foreach statement its showing same name again and again

Comment: category_id is common in both table like if oc_category has category_id 106 the name for it will be in oc_category_description which contains category_id 106 same in common

Comment: The join is the only sensible thing to do here, a group isn't necessary afaict.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table to get the info:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oc_category a 
        LEFT JOIN oc_category_description b ON a.category_id = b.category_id";
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer it is working fine. but i can't understand your code. Can you please elaborate it. Really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a join condition between those two tables lest you end up with a Cartesian product:

```
SELECT oc_category.*, oc_category_description.name
FROM oc_category
jOIN oc_category_description USING (category_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 tables even without telling to mysql how to join them, due to this reason you are getting slowness. You can use below 2 approaches:

First Medhod: If it is confirm that oc_category_description table have corresponding category_id against oc_category.

```
$sql = "SELECT oc.column1,oc.column2,des.column1 FROM oc_category cat, oc_category_description des where cat.category_id = des.category_id";
```

Second Medhod: If some time oc_category_description table have corresponding category_id against oc_category and some time not and you want all rows from master table like oc_category.

```
$sql = "SELECT oc.column1,oc.column2,des.column1 FROM oc_category cat left join oc_category_description des on cat.category_id = des.category_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

For together two different tables USING(UNION AND JOIN)

1.Union

```
SELECT columnlist
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT columnlist
FROM   table2
```

2.JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
        LEFT JOIN TABLE2  ON TABLE1.category_id = TABLE2.category_id"
```